# achemso \keyword and \abbreviation command don't work

Tags: formatting, achemso

I'm preparing a paper using the `achemso` package. I used it before (around 2 years ago) and everything worked fine. However, if I use the `\keyword` and `\abbreviation` commands now I don't get what I got two years ago, even with the file from two years ago it doesn't work anymore.

Here's what I mean:

```
\abbreviations{abb1, abb2}
\keywords{key1, key2, key3}
```

and I use the following documentclass:

```
\documentclass[journal=nalefd,manuscript=letter]{achemso}
```

When I used it two years ago the abbreviations didn't show up in the manuscript and the keywords were displayed before the abstract like this:

> KEYWORDS: key1, key2, key3

Now I get the following after the abstract:

> **Keywords**
>
> abb1, abb2

And then follows my main text. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of `achemso` do you have installed? This is 'works for me' with the current release and journal ID you've given.

Comment: I downloaded it again but it didn't change. It says packaged on 2013-08-27.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The minor formatting changes reflect what the ACS seem to want in manuscripts, based on user feedback. As `achemso` is for material that is *retypeset* by the publisher I'm always at pains to point out that appearance is really not important as long as the editorial office concerned will accept the manuscript.

Comment: I suppose you're right, it's just a style issue. However, if you or someone else has an idea how I could solve it I'd still appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean 'solve': the change has been made because the ACS editorial offices seem to prefer the newer version to the older one. If there are specific issues with the office for _Nano Letters_ then I can make another change: each office is a 'law unto itself' so keeping track of all of the requirements is hard work.

Comment: The key point is that the class is purely for submissions to the ACS: stability is not important, getting submissions into the required format is. The journals can and do alter there requirements, so the class has to change over time.

Comment: Ok, sorry for not replying in a while, but here's my problem:
I don't mind that it looks different from what I had before. The thing is that if the people at ACS did some changes to the achemso package then I would expect it to still give me a decent layout. But it just writes "KEYWORDS" in bold letters without actually listing the keywords. The next line lists the abbreviations without saying that these are abbreviations.

Comment: So that's why I think there's something wrong on my end.

Comment: Just in case someone is interested: Joseph figured out the problem and it's fixed in the current version now.

Comment: Joseph,  my recent experience is that one of the more important editorial offices DOES NOT accept the manuscript without the keywords showing.    And though the fix that you offered \setkeys{acs}{keywords = true},  works, it is NOT in the documentation in a way that it can be understood by a naive user.   So this needs to be fixed, for real. Seriously.

Answer (score -2):

Open the `achemso.cls` and change
`keywords      = false` to `keywords      = true` (line 279 in `achemso.cls` file)
you can do similar for abbreviations if you want.

Comment: Won't work has the question is about some printing choices for the output rather than turning the output on/off. If all you want to do is the latter, `\setkeys{acs}{keywords = true}` after the `\documentclass` line will do it.

Comment: One should never modify the original files. You can patch them or redefine the necessary macros in the TeX file. Modifying originals can even lead to package update problems.

Comment: For the flaggers, please use flags for structurally wrong ones but not for answers that you would not agree.